# selectors not and siblings

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 3 divs and each have one black and red rectangle. I want that when you click on one of the black rectangles all the reds will change the color to white except the red one that is sibling of the black clicked.
  I don't want to add any more classes ids  or change the dom.
I've been trying with no success. thx in advanced.

```js
  $(document).ready(function(){
 $(".black-rectangle").click(function(){
  $(".red-rectangle").not(this.siblings(".rec2")).css("background-color","#fff");
 })
})
```

```css
    .black-rectangle{
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background-color:#000;
  border: 5px solid green;
  margin-top: 10px;
 } 
 .red-rectangle{
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background-color: red;
  border: 5px solid green;
  margin-top: 10px;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div>  
    <div class="black-rectangle"></div>
    <div class="red-rectangle"</div>
  </div> 
  <div>  
    <div class="black-rectangle"></div>
    <div class="red-rectangle"</div>
  </div> 
  <div>  
    <div class="black-rectangle"></div>
    <div class="red-rectangle"</div>
  </div>                               
</body>
```

Comment: `this.siblings` should be `$(this).siblings`. `siblings` is a jQuery method, not a DOM method.

Comment: There's no `rec2` class in your HTML. Also, all the `red-rectangle` DIVs are missing their `>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`siblings` is a jQuery method, but `this` is a DOM element, not a jQuery object. You need to use `$(this)` to wrap it in a jQuery object.

There's no `rec2` class in your HTML, so I changed it to just `.siblings()` with no selector.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".black-rectangle").click(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    $(".red-rectangle").not($this.siblings()).css("background-color", "#fff");
  })
})
```

```css
.black-rectangle {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background-color: #000;
  border: 5px solid green;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
.red-rectangle {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background-color: red;
  border: 5px solid green;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div>
    <div class="black-rectangle"></div>
    <div class="red-rectangle"></div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div class="black-rectangle"></div>
    <div class="red-rectangle"></div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div class="black-rectangle"></div>
    <div class="red-rectangle"></div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Don't define your own `this` variable, it's special.

Comment: See my update, it works if you do `var $this = $(this)`.